Git cherry-pick hash differences when comparing
i have two staging and uat branches. I cherry-picked some commits from staging to uat. Later when I want to see the differences between these branches it shows the cherry-picked commits because the hash would change. So its been very difficult to track exactly which commits are remaining. how do I tackle this? Is there a better way? I used:
git rev-list staging ^uat --no-merges

This question is similar to: How to see which commits in one branch aren't in the other?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can try git log with the --cherry-pick or --cherry-mark option:
git log --graph --cherry-pick uat..staging
# or
git log --graph --cherry-mark uat..staging

(see git help log, and note that git rev-list has the same option)
or git cherry
git cherry -v uat staging

(git help cherry)

git cherry -v uat staging showed me the commits which are already cherry-picked to uat from staging.

Yes, the important information is the leading symbol. - means the commit was picked, + means it isn't

You can address the challenge of tracking which commits are remaining between your staging and uat branches after cherry-picking, by running this command below:
first checkout the staging branch
git checkout staging

Then do this after:
git cherry -v uat staging

OR
Try this command to avoid seeing the commits that have been cherry-picked.
git log --cherry-pick --oneline --graph --left-right staging...uat


it showed me the commits which are already cherry-picked to uat from staging

@LokeshBajracharya I have updated the commands let's see what happens
